# Comparing two objects in Java .. each object has two fields

Tags: java, class, exception, compare

I want to compare between two cards in poker hand .. each of them has a suit and a rank and I want to check if there are duplicates to create an exception .. need help with this piece of code please ! is it ok to use the equals method or it is wrong ?!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pokerhand {

    public final int CARDS_NUMBER = 5;
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public Pokerhand (Card card1 , Card card2, Card card3, Card card4, Card card5)
    {
        cards.add(card1);
        cards.add(card2);
        cards.add(card3);
        cards.add(card4);
        cards.add(card5);
    }

    private boolean check(ArrayList<Card> cards)
    {
        if (cards.size() != CARDS_NUMBER)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect number of cards!! ");

        for ( int i=0 ; i<= cards.size(); i++)
        {
            if (cards.get(i).equals(cards.get(i+1)))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicat card");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `equals()` is great to use, as long as you have implemented it in your `Card` class.

Comment: You should override equals() in Card class.

Comment: its okay to use equals, but i assume equals is not implemented in in your Card class. so youhave to override equalsmethod in your card class.

Comment: 1. Have you overridden the `equals()` method in `Card` class? 2. `i<= cards.size();` this condition is wrong. Change it to `i< cards.size();` 3. The logic of `if` needs a change or the looping needs to change.

Comment: this means that it will not be able to compare the 2 fields ?! need to define it you mean

Comment: yes right. if you not define it, it will compare the reference and its only true for cards.get(i).equals(cards.get(i))

Comment: if (cards.get(i).equals(cards.get(i+1)))  there is a logical problem. you compare the card only with cards that appears after it in the list. you need two nested for-loops.

Comment: Implementing `equals()` correctly means that you also have to implement `hashCode()` in a matching way. Don't override just one of them.

Comment: @R.J I am intending to sort the cards then this will work

Comment: @EmanHamed - Let me give you a small heads-up. `i+1` will go out-of-bounds once `i` becomes `cards.size() - 1`. Try it yourself and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider implementing Comparable in your Card class.  Say each card has rank (1-king) and suit (hearts, diamonds, etc.) The method compareTo would look like:

```
public int compareTo(Card anotherCard) {
  if (this.suit.equals(anotherCard.suit) && this.rank.equals(anotherCard.rank)) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (this.suit.equals(anotherCard.suit)) {
    return this.rank.compareTo(anotherCard.rank);
  }
  else {
    return this.suit.compareTo(anotherCard.suit);
  }
}
```

Then you should just use card1.compareTo(card2) == 0 instead of card1.equals(card2)

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `equals` method, or it just compare the reference of two objects, rather than the value of the cards.

Here is a example:

```
public class Card {

    private int rank;

    private int suit;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (!(obj instanceof Card)) {
            return false;
        }
        Card c = (Card) obj;
        return this.rank == c.rank && this.suit == c.suit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (cards.get(i).equals(cards.get(i+1)))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicat card");
```

Try:

```
if(cards.get(i).getSuit() == cards.get(i+1).getSuit() 
   && cards.get(i).getRank() == cards.get(i+1).getRank())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicat card");
```

This way you are comparing the values within the objects as opposed to comparing the object references are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe model this better using enums. For example:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class PokerGame {

    public enum Suit {
        SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS
    }

    public enum Rank {
        ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGH, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING
    }

    public enum Card {
        ACE_OF_SPADES(Rank.ACE, Suit.SPADES), 
        TWO_OF_SPADES(Rank.TWO, Suit.SPADES), 
        THREE_OF_SPADES(Rank.THREE, Suit.SPADES), 
        FOUR_OF_SPADES(Rank.FOUR, Suit.SPADES), 
        FIVE_OF_SPADES(Rank.FIVE, Suit.SPADES);
        // the other cards left as an exercise for the reader (-;

        private Rank rank;
        private Suit suit;

        Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public Rank rank() {
            return rank;
        }

        public Suit suit() {
            return suit;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumSet<Card> deck = EnumSet.allOf(Card.class);
        System.out.println(deck.size());
    }
}
```

You can then use EnumSet to create decks or hands of cards, always guaranteed to be unique.

Additional remark, the following logic is flawed:

```
    for ( int i=0 ; i<= cards.size(); i++)
    {
        if (cards.get(i).equals(cards.get(i+1)))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicat card");
    }
```

This will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException because you are iterating up to cards.size() and acccessing cards.get(i + 1). Furthermore this will not detect non-adjacent duplicates.